# Multiple Swift Packages with XCFramework binary targets result in "ProcessXCFramework - Multiple commands produce module.modulemap" Error

Tags: swift-package-manager, xcframework

I have 2 Swift Package dependencies which both have a XCFramework binary target. Both xcframeworks have:

- .a file
- Headers folder with .h files and a module.modulemap file.

When I add these packages to my project I get the error:

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include/module.modulemap'

Command: ProcessXCFramework /Users/omran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../SourcePackages/checkouts/zebrabarcodescanner/Sources/ZebraScannerSDK.xcframework /Users/omran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libsymbolbt-sdk.a ios simulator

Command: ProcessXCFramework /Users/omran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../SourcePackages/checkouts/verifonesdk/Sources/VMF.xcframework /Users/omran/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/../Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/VMF.a iOS simulator
```

Seems like Xcode is trying to write both modulemaps to the same location... Is this a bug?

Comment: hey i am having the exact same problem - were u able to fix it?

Comment: @Cesar No I have not found a solution yet. Are your XCFrameworks third party or did you develop them yourself?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to find a solution for this, sorry for the late reply ser @omranK. Answering your comment in concrete, I was using a XCFramework third party and I developed mine too, inside of both XCFrameworks, they had the `module.modulemap` & a `.h` file, and I was getting the same error you're getting.

The way I fixed it is by modifying my XCFramework, to just have the static library and manually adding the headers and module in my app, and defining the path of those in the `Package.swift` path (I was using SPM)

So, let's say I have `MyLibrary` which depends on two libraries: `MyExternalLibrary` and `AnotherExternalLibrary`, my `Package.swift` looks something like:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v15)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibrary"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(name: "MyExternalLibrary", path: "../my_library"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/org/another_external_library", from: "0.1.1")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            dependencies: [
                "MyExternalLibrary",
                "AnotherLibrary"
            ],
            cSettings: [
                .headerSearchPath("../../include")
            ]
        ),
    ],
    swiftLanguageVersions: [.v5]
)
```

The important part is the `cSettings`, where we explicitly define the headers path. Note that the `include` folder is in the root of my app.

This solution was inspired from this link: https://www.reddit.com/r/swift/comments/oi632j/multiple_binary_xcframeworks_in_swift_package/

Hope this is helpful ser :-)